# Understanding stream.map in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, java-8, java-stream

I am launching in java some SQL queries, which will return some data that looks like :

> [**ID**,Description,WhateverColumn,...,...,**ImportantNumber**]

Sample:

> [**1**,"Desc",...,...,**1**]
>
> [**1**,"Desc",...,...,**2**]
>
> [**1**,"Desc",...,...,**3**]
>
> [**2**,"Desc",...,...,**1**]
>
> [**3**,"Desc",...,...,**3**]
>
> [**3**,"Desc",...,...,**5**]

I am using the following List to store it in memory:

```
List<Object[]> myList = queryLaunched(...);
```

Later on, I want to do some operations with this `List` of `Object[]`:

> [[1,"Desc",...,...,1],[1,"Desc",...,...,2],...]

and I am trying to use stream.map in the following way:

```
myList.stream().map(item -> System.out.println(item.toString()));
```

but I just receive this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `Stream<Object>` to `void`

Wherever I look in google I just find samples made with `List<Class>`, not with `List<Object[]>`.

How could I print, and therefore, after it, start doing operations with each of the items in that list?

Comment: I am sorry Tom, I agree with you. When i posted the question I was sure I had to use map, and Eran made me see why I shouldn't do that. But now I see it is correctly answered in that question what I was trying to do. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` is used to transform a `Stream<TypeA>` to a `Stream<TypeB>`. In order to print the elements, don't use `map`.

You can use a terminal operation :

```
myList.stream().forEach(item -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(item)));
```

or an intermediate operation (which can be followed by additional operations) :

```
myList.stream().peek(item -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(item)))... ;
```

Since your elements are arrays, you should print them with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(item))`.

Comment: Or without lambdas: `myList.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Hmmm, answer looks pretty cool. I must be missing something though: When I use your option with forEach it prints all the elements in the array perfectly. However, If i substitute "forEach" for "peek" it doesnt seem to be doing anything. Do I need to do any extra thing?

Comment: @Mayday `peek` is an intermediate operation, so it will only be executed if you have some terminal operation after it (such as `collect`, `reduce`, `forEach`, etc...). Besides that, it may not be executed for all the elements of the stream (it will only be executed for elements which were required for executing the terminal operation).

Comment: Alright, that explains it. Sorry, I am still trying to learn these new concepts on Java SE 8. Thank you very much for your answers, were really helpfull :)